# Headphones not working

Tags: headphones, software-update

bought Razer Tiamat V2, and when I plug them into "Line out" hole in my PC I get the sound, but my mic does not seem to be working. Plugging it into other holes does not give either sound/mic. Is it possible that there is a software problem I could check, or should I take it to the shop? Asking cause I live in a shithole and its an hour drive. Thanks.

Comment: Line Out is output only. You need to buy an appropriate headphone/mike splitter. Something like https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Headphone-Microphone-Splitter-Headphones-Silver/dp/B00Y4663GG

Answer (score 0):

Simple short answer.. what about the USB connector?  It should do both at the same time.

First of all, none of those five plugs will work for both mic and audio from the same plug.  If you notice, all of them have three sections,  plugs that do both have four sections (like the picture below).

1. Plug the green plug into line out.
2. Plug the pink plug into microphone.

If your PC only has one hole (that does both) and you insist on not using USB, you will need to buy a splitter.  The green and pink sockets should be self explanitory after looking at your headset ;)

[image: Something like this...]
Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I get that, but my headset only has 1 plug?

Comment: DOUGH! My bad..  was looking at the V2.2 not the V2.  You already have the four part jack.  Sometimes, getting specific mics to work in windows 10 can be a pain.  Have you tried going to Settings->Sound and making sure you have an input device selected?  If so.. on that same settings page, go down to "Sound Control Panel" (which is an almost hidden link).  It will give you finite control over the input.  That should get you closer. :/

Comment: DOUGH x2.. does your computer have separate inputs for mic and line in?  My laptop has both in one jack so I wasn't thinking.  If so, you need the OPPOSITE of the picture I posted above.  JUST LIKE @DavidPostill suggested.